# Multiplying numbers in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I need a loop to multiply part of a list. I have multiply every Nth element (except 0th) by M. The list is called numbers, the multiplier is M, and the loop should start multiplying at the Nth number.
This is what I have:

```
for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
  numbers[i]= int(numbers[i])

for M in range (N, len(numbers)):
  if numbers[N] > 0:
    numbers.append[N]
  if numbers[N] < 0:
    total = numbers
    print (total)
```

It keeps returning the wrong output, I've tried everything I can think of to fix it but it still won't work.

Comment: `.append[N]`? You do not call a function with square brackets.

Comment: I've tried that it didn't work.

Comment: But it does not make any sense, you call functions with round brackets (i.e. `numbers.append(1)`, and you do not need to append anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You usually multiply a number with the asterisk (`*`). So we can multiply the `i`-th number with:

```
numbers[i] *= M
```

To multiply every `N`-th element except the first one, we can construct a range:

```
for i in range(N, len(numbers), N):
    numbers[i] *= M
```

The last argument of the `range` is the `step`, it means that we thus each time increment `i`, until reach `len(numbers)`

Comment: Shouldn't the `range(N, len(numbers), N)` be `range(N, len(numbers)+1, N)`? Otherwise it will miss the last element?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: no, since the last index of a list is `len(thelist)-1`. This is why you see `for i in range(len(thelist))` in code frequently: because that does not exclude the last element as well.

Comment: `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` with `list(range(2,len(l),2))` gives `[2,4,6,8]`

Comment: @GarbageCollector: that is indeed the expected output, since the last index is `9`, which is odd. If you write `[l[i] for i in range(2, len(l), 2)]` you will obtain `[3, 5, 7, 9]`.

Comment: Ah right! Sorry got a bit confused with `Nth` notation in question.

Answer (score 1):

There a quite a few problems and oddities in your code:

- you use `M` as the loop variable, thus overwriting the multiplier stored in `M`; better use `i` as in your first loop
- your are appending to the list, instead of overwriting the numbers with `numbers[i] = numbers[i] * M` or just `numbers[i] *= M`
- I don't see how the `> 0` and `< 0` checks relate to your question, but you should probably check `numbers[i]` instead of `numbers[N]`, the letter being always the same
- also, I don't see why you assign the entire `numbers` list (instead of e.g. just `numbers[i]` to `total` and print it...

You could also use a list comprehension and assign back to a slice of the original list:

```
>>> N, M = 3, 10
>>> numbers = list(range(10))
>>> numbers[N::N] = [x*M for x in numbers[N::N]]
>>> numbers
[0, 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 60, 7, 8, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers]
```

this is for the first function. It's called a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoWgzG_r2qo) The second one you got `M` and `N` mixed up i guess. What is `N` anyways?

Comment: I think N is 3, and M is 5

Answer (score 0):

With `map`:

```
map(lambda (i, el): el*M if i%N==0 else el, enumerate(numbers))
```

Skipping the first index:

```
map(lambda (i, el): el*M if i%N==0 and i>0 else el, enumerate(numbers))
```